# I'm trying to code a discord bot in Javascript but it keeps saying "Declaration or statement expected. ts(1128)"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Here's the code, it says the "else" statement needs a "Declaration or statement"
(The underscores in the .addfield() are actually words but I don't want anyone to steal my ideas)

```
    if(command === 'start'){
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('START MENU')
            .addField('Options-')
            .addField('Hello and welcome to the world of pokémon! Pick your first pokémon from the list below with the command `p!pick <pokemon>`')
            .addField('Bulbasaur, Charmander, Squirtle')
            .addField('Chikorita, Cyndaquil, Totodile')
            .addField('Treecko, Torchic, Mudkip'
            .addField('Turtwig, Chimchar, Piplup')
            .addField('Snivy, Tepig, Oshawott')
            .addField('Chespin, Fennekin, Froakie')
            .addField('Rowlet, Litten, Popplio')
            .addField('Grookey, Scorbunny, Sobble')
            .addField('______,______,______')
            .setColor(0x036f5a))
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }}); else {
        message.channel.send('INVALID COMMAND')
    }
```

Comment: Get rid of the `;` before `else`

Comment: That fixes that problem but then it tells me to add a ; again

Comment: As the answer below says, it looks like you've got one too many `}`

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet my 2 pence on the double curly brackets, parenthesis and the semicolon before `else`. IMO, it should be only a single closing curly bracket.

Comment: Sorry, but that only adds 3 more errors. It doesn't even solve the error at hand either. Thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: @TomasAytoJr. if you don't mention exactly what the errors are, nobody can help.

Comment: @TomasAytoJr. Well, TBH I just copied the code into Notepad++ and it was obvious that the one of the curly brackets and the parenthesis do not actually close anything. Also in JS `if` and `else` are not separated by `;` because they are parts of the same statement. You sure you copied the  code properly (e.g. I often have to leave out bits & pieces and this messes up the code here).